# Npm compiler : Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

Tags: npm, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli

I did setup https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli Vue CLI with the [webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack) and it works fine. 
But when i change something in template file it throws below error.

Kindly help on the below issue,

```
> Starting dev server...


 DONE  Compiled successfully in 2703ms                                6:00:35 PM

> Listening at http://localhost:8083
 WAIT  Compiling...                                                   6:01:05 PM


c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSy
stem.js:145
                        if(key.startsWith(what))
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
    at Storage.purge (c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\node_modules\enhanced-resolve
\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:145:10)
    at Storage.purge (c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\node_modules\enhanced-resolve
\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:150:9)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.purge (c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\node_modules\en
hanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:259:20)
    at EventEmitter.watcher.once (c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\node_modules\webp
ack\lib\node\NodeWatchFileSystem.js:42:26)
    at EventEmitter.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at EventEmitter._onTimeout (c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\node_modules\watchp
ack\lib\watchpack.js:142:7)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:380:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:244:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x8
6)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! dktrgo@1.0.0 dev: `node build/dev-server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the dktrgo@1.0.0 dev script 'node build/dev-server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the dktrgo package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build/dev-server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs dktrgo
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls dktrgo
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     c:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\npm-debug.log
```

Thank you

Comment: Problem is not related to vue-cli, seems to be caused by a dependency of webpack-dev-server.

https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/issues/102

Comment: Great, Thank you. Its solved my problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to reproduce in v3.4.0, but not in v3.4.1 (which was released about 5 hours later).

To confirm you're on v3.4.0:

```
npm list enhanced-resolve
```

Please update enhanced-resolve to v3.4.1:

```
npm i enhanced-resolve
```

Comment: Here are the relevant github issues: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1005 and https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/issues/97

Comment: Doesn't work for me 
`npm list enhanced-resolve
training_front@1.0.0 /home/users/webgasmi/projects/training_front
├── enhanced-resolve@3.4.1
└─┬ webpack@2.7.0
     └── enhanced-resolve@3.4.0`